# What is the Hasse Diagram to this partial order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

[image: dia]

I think I know the answer but I am not quite sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you think is the answer?

Comment: I will try to describe it as I don't know any other way of showing you (not used to this site much).

Comment: a------c whilst also having b-----d-----c, if you get me?

Answer (score 3):

Think: Transitive reduction ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram
[image]

Comment: Just to check, does that make the minimal element(s) B rather the minimal element(s) being A and B? My question more being: what makes B a minimal element (if it is) as opposed to A and B being on the same level? Is it simply because B has a longer order/partially ordered to more elements?

Comment: If I were to refer to {a,b} as a pair, would that make sense? Because aren't pairs meant to be on the same level?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are maximal elements (assuming your arrows are that way up?). "at the same level" becomes dubious in some larger posets. Have a look at the example in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram#A_%22good%22_Hasse_diagram

Comment: It's important to understand that a and b are not comparable in this partial order.  There is no reasonable way to evaluate them being "on the same level"

Comment: To emphasize the last point: One could move A so that it was on the same 'level' as B, and it would still be a valid Hasse diagram. What matters is its structure as a directed graph, not the particular placement of nodes.